# Fetch document using axios as streams in node.js and pass data to client

Tags: node.js, express, axios, blob, node-streams

I am trying to fetch documents via node.js using axios and send the binary data to downstream applications(react in my case). I tried using responseType with arrayBuffer first but that is causing image type data to get corrupted. I got a recommendation to use responseType as stream. However I am not finding the write way to send the response back to the client. My current code looks like this:

```
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "x_correlation_id": correlationId,
      responseType: "stream",
    },
    url: url,
  };
  axios
    .request(requestOptions)
    .then((response) => {
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", response.headers["content-type"]);
      response.pipe(res);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      errorHandler(error, req, res);
    });
```

With the above code I am getting response.pipe is not a function. If I do not mention a responseType or responseType as an arrayBuffer I see a corrupted file for image types while PDF type documents work fine.

Comment: Find a solution yet?